# C# HttpPost-Postman Json always null

Tags: c#, json, postman, http-post

I'm Trying to make pass a Json to a webservice in c#.
But when i pass the Json, my function in c# doesn't save it(returns null).
This is my c# code.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult test(Product producto)
    {
        var model = producto;
        return Json(new { success = true, result = "My usuario es " + model.Name});
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is what i'm sending by postman

[Postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bJXj.png)

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost/ws/test' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"Id":1,"Name":"abc","Category":"asd"}'
```

Why when i'm trying to get the producto.Name returns null??
Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Change your action header:

```
public JsonResult test([FromBody]Product producto)
{
...your code
}
```